# Bad parameters on attach or create database - CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 is not defined

Tags: macos, qt5, firebird, macos-big-sur, firebird2.5

I know the problem is not recent, but I've tried all solutions I found and the problem persists. I'm on Mac OS Big sur and I've a Qt 5.15 application. On my dev machine, all works fine, but when I test on another Mac, I've always the error *"Bad parameters on attach or create database - CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 is not defined Error opening database"*.

The problem is reproduced on three Macs.
I've tried to:

1. backup the database and restore it on test Mac.
2. using Firebird 3 instead of 2.5.9
3. use Firebird Classic instead of SS
4. add intl dylib to the bundle

But no alternative works. So that I'm returning to the community guessing any help, idea & solution

Comment: I would recommend asking on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).

Comment: You mention you included intl dylib in the bundle. Are you not using Firebird server? Because you wouldn't need to include anything manually then. Also did you also include the intl.conf, and is it in the right location?

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, I've asked firebird-support but no response yet. I've tried with Firebird Super Server and Classic but same issue. For that, I've included the intl files but really I don't know where I must put them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about the Mac build, but I would expect everything to be already in the right place without you having to move around files manually. In any case, I don't see a recent question about this error on firebird-support.